# Approach for starting/stopping job at certain time

Tags: c#, logic

I have a console application that writes data to a database through out the day. I'd like to only carry out the job between two times. At the moment I'm using a while loop and checking the current time against the time range I'd like to run the job in. This takes up a bit of CPU power though. Is there a neater way of doing this?

```
While(true)
{
    if(current > DateTime.Today.AddHours(6) && current < DateTime.Today.AddHours(20))
    {
        ---DO STUFF
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, consider using [`System.Timers.Timer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) class like below. Here, the interval is set to 1000 milliseconds (1 second). So after every 1 second it will raise `Elapsed` event when you can perform the task you want.

```
Timer tmr = new Timer(1000);
tmr.Elapsed += elapsedHandler;

private void elapsedHandler(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
  //do your work
}
```

Per your comment, in that case create your `exe` and create a DOS batch script to run that exe. Then use `Windows task scheduler` to run the `dos script` in specified time range.

Comment: But if I wanted the work to run everyday between 06:00 and 20:00 then I would have 2 timers. One for the amount of time the job should run and one for the amount of time that must pass before the job runs again. Is that correct?

Comment: @MitchelStuartFountaine, see edit in answer if that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Rahul. I was using Windows Task Scheduler to Start/End the console application. It would kill the process but I was struggling to start it because of dependencies. So unfortunately Task Scheduler is out. I will also be making this into a service eventually so would like the service to only do the work between mentioned times.

Comment: @MitchelStuartFountaine, yes go for using `Timer`. You can define the interval time accordingly per your requirement. so since you want to start it after 6 hours, set the interval to `6*60*60*1000`

Answer (score 1):

You can keep the same approach, but use a sleep of 1ms or bigger, and the cpu will be less used